# Using login.salesforce.com, log user in salesforce with SAML

Tags: saml, salesforce-classic, identity

Workflow is Salesforce is an IdP and Okta being SP. Expectation is set that provide a generic way of login wherein users are not scoped to specific domain in Salesforce.

I have created an OAuth connected app in Salesforce with my custom domain. So, I configured Consumer API and Secret keys with OAuth Login URL as `https://login.salesforce.com`. This helps me achieves my expectation.

But I am trying to configure same workflow with SAML instead of OAuth. However this does not works. I can only log with the org-specific emails.
How do I achieve the expected workflow?

Comment: did you follow this `Hands-on Training: Enable Single Sign-on with SAML and Salesforce Identity`  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIA1MZrNaAE

Answer (score 0):

If you have to be use Salesforce as IdP then for using SAML, you must create My Domain.

> My domain is preferred because

Any of the org exists in same instance (say na11), **you can only be logged in into one org**. Now you have two orgs in na11, then through my domain you can logged into both at the same time, Salesforce can sort out the sessions.

Secondly, If you don’t use my domain then you can go to single sign on portal and jump into the orgs and if you use my domain, you will go directly to the org. your bookmark, deep links, browser auto completing, chatter notification via email all works seamlessly using one identity

OAuth is good for providing authorization, where SAML is generally used for SSO authentication.

Refer [Customize Your Login Process with My Domain](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/identity/modules/identity_login/units/identity_login_my_domain)

Also, follow [Hands-on Training: Enable Single Sign-on with SAML and Salesforce Identity](http://youtube.com/watch?v=kIA1MZrNaAE)